# Read data into vuex store from external file

Tags: vue.js

I am starting out with vue to provide a front end for my home sensor/device setup. The set up is configured outside of vue and I wish to read in the current state of the system into vue when the app is loaded. I am using vuex to share values between components. Is there a way to read in to the vuex state from either a flat file (json) outside of the app or even a db such as sqlite?
I would envisage that the population of the initial state would be achieved by a mutation as the app loads. I can’t seem to find an explanation of how to achieve this (so maybe it can't be done or I am missing something)

Thank you

Martyn

Comment: How you want to reach the db? If is through an API call, sure you can!

Comment: @Raffobaffo, thanks, reading from a file would be easiest, but db would be okay.  I am not sure what you mean in your answer. Would you mind elaborating please?

Comment: If you are planning to connect to a SQL database directly from the browser (the vue app) that's not possible, or at least really uncommon. Usually to access the dB you connect to your serve through an http request

Comment: @Raffobaffo - thanks.  So the http request is done as the app loads?  do you have any links that might get me on my way please.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I id in an answer. Enjoy "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for comments.
Sure, take a look here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Comment: Thanks, your pointer led me to this https://dev.to/firstclown/how-to-query-your-api-using-vuex-in-your-vue-application-11c8